# Not able to install node-syslog

Tags: node.js, winston

When doing npm install node-syslog i am getting the error as below

```
 In file included from ../node-syslog.h:13:0,
                     from ../syslog.cc:1:
  ../compat.h:27:2: error: #error "Unsupported node.js version."
     #error "Unsupported node.js version."
     ^
    ../compat.h:62:53: error: ‘FunctionCallback’ has not been declared
                                               FunctionCallback callback =

    I am using the versions of
    node.js--V5.7.1
    npm -- v3.8.0
    syslog -- v3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the header file [compat.h](https://github.com/schamane/node-syslog/blob/master/compat.h#L24-L32):

```
#define COMPAT_IOJS_1_x 42

#if NODE_MAJOR_VERSION == 0 && NODE_MINOR_VERSION >= 11
  #define COMPAT_NODE_VERSION 12  // v0.12
#elif NODE_MAJOR_VERSION == 0 && NODE_MINOR_VERSION == 10
  #define COMPAT_NODE_VERSION 10  // v0.10
#elif NODE_MODULE_VERSION >= COMPAT_IOJS_1_x // io.js semver 1.0.x
  #define COMPAT_NODE_VERSION COMPAT_IOJS_1_x
#else
  #error "Unsupported node.js version."
#endif
```

I'm guessing (someone correct me if I'm wrong) this means that you need to have node v0.10+ (but major version numeber 0), and thus I suspect you are running a node version that is too recent. There is [an issue](https://github.com/schamane/node-syslog/issues/51) on their Github related to this.

If you want to use a different node version, you can take a look at [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)